# Failed to get convolution algorithm error in tensorflow

Tags: nvidia, cuda, tensorflow

I installed Cuda, cudann, and TensorFlow by strictly following instructions on tensorflow.org.
I had my ubuntu switched to the Nvidia card during the installation.
After verifying the installation I switched back to intel. 
Now on compiling my codes I'm getting this message in the terminal :

```
2019-11-26 19:24:24.781299: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1
2019-11-26 19:24:24.830457: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:1006] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2019-11-26 19:24:24.831899: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1618] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce MX150 major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.5315
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0
2019-11-26 19:24:24.983890: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.0
2019-11-26 19:24:25.001409: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10.0
2019-11-26 19:24:25.009430: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10.0
2019-11-26 19:24:25.030189: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10.0
2019-11-26 19:24:25.048404: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10.0
2019-11-26 19:24:25.067131: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10.0
2019-11-26 19:24:25.095875: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
2019-11-26 19:24:25.096289: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:1006] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2019-11-26 19:24:25.099040: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:1006] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2019-11-26 19:24:25.100673: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1746] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2019-11-26 19:24:25.101394: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
2019-11-26 19:24:25.135574: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:94] CPU Frequency: 1800000000 Hz
2019-11-26 19:24:25.137917: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x5619ea60e930 executing computations on platform Host. Devices:
2019-11-26 19:24:25.137997: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:175]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
2019-11-26 19:24:25.270223: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:1006] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2019-11-26 19:24:25.271459: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x5619ebdb8290 executing computations on platform CUDA. Devices:
2019-11-26 19:24:25.271500: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:175]   StreamExecutor device (0): GeForce MX150, Compute Capability 6.1
2019-11-26 19:24:25.271757: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:1006] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2019-11-26 19:24:25.272737: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1618] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce MX150 major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.5315
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0
2019-11-26 19:24:25.272802: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.0
2019-11-26 19:24:25.272831: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10.0
2019-11-26 19:24:25.272858: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10.0
2019-11-26 19:24:25.272882: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10.0
2019-11-26 19:24:25.272913: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10.0
2019-11-26 19:24:25.272940: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10.0
2019-11-26 19:24:25.272966: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
2019-11-26 19:24:25.273065: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:1006] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2019-11-26 19:24:25.274126: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:1006] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2019-11-26 19:24:25.275065: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1746] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2019-11-26 19:24:25.275131: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.0
2019-11-26 19:24:25.277086: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1159] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2019-11-26 19:24:25.277112: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1165]      0 
2019-11-26 19:24:25.277124: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1178] 0:   N 
2019-11-26 19:24:25.277325: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:1006] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2019-11-26 19:24:25.278329: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:1006] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2019-11-26 19:24:25.279323: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1304] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 1323 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce MX150, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
```

So is my GPU working or do I need to do something else?
Thanks for answering but looks I've run into a new one while trying to run
convolutional layers.
The error says:

```
2019-11-29 20:59:03.481920: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10.0
2019-11-29 20:59:06.074691: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
2019-11-29 20:59:06.171580: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:329] Could not create cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED
2019-11-29 20:59:06.171825: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:337] Possibly insufficient driver version: 418.87.1
2019-11-29 20:59:06.171902: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:329] Could not create cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED
2019-11-29 20:59:06.171993: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:337] Possibly insufficient driver version: 418.87.1
2019-11-29 20:59:06.172777: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/base_collective_executor.cc:216] BaseCollectiveExecutor::StartAbort Unknown: Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above.
     [[{{node sequential/conv2d/Conv2D}}]]
   32/50000 [..............................] - ETA: 2:43:50Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sample3.py", line 54, in 
    validation_data=(test_images, test_labels))
  File "/home/encrypto/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 728, in fit
    use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
  File "/home/encrypto/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2.py", line 324, in fit
    total_epochs=epochs)
  File "/home/encrypto/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2.py", line 123, in run_one_epoch
    batch_outs = execution_function(iterator)
  File "/home/encrypto/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2_utils.py", line 86, in execution_function
    distributed_function(input_fn))
  File "/home/encrypto/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/def_function.py", line 457, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
  File "/home/encrypto/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/def_function.py", line 520, in _call
    return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)
  File "/home/encrypto/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py", line 1823, in __call__
    return graph_function._filtered_call(args, kwargs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "/home/encrypto/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py", line 1141, in _filtered_call
    self.captured_inputs)
  File "/home/encrypto/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py", line 1224, in _call_flat
    ctx, args, cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager)
  File "/home/encrypto/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py", line 511, in call
    ctx=ctx)
  File "/home/encrypto/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/execute.py", line 67, in quick_execute
    six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
  File "", line 3, in raise_from
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnknownError:  Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above.
     [[node sequential/conv2d/Conv2D (defined at /home/encrypto/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py:1751) ]] [Op:__inference_distributed_function_1055]

Function call stack:
distributed_function
```

Please tell me what to do about this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the messages you're getting in your terminal, i.e:

```
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1618] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce MX150 major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.5315
```

TensorFlow is using your Nvidia Graphic Card.
In addition: run `pip freeze` (if you're using Python3, use `pip3` instead of `pip`)  to see that you've already installed tensorflow-gpu **wich will only run when you're using Nvidia Graphic Card**.